# Undefined state provider

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting `unknown state provider: editProvider <- edit <- FooController` in my code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.handler.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('edit', {
        url: '/foo/edit',
        resolve: {
            values: ['FooService', 
            function (FooService) {
                return FooService.getSomeData();
            }]
        },
        templateUrl: '',
        controller: 'FooController'
    });
}]);
app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'FooService', 'edit', function ($scope, $http, $state, FooService, edit) {
   console.log(edit.data);
}]);
```

The error appears inside the controller code - what's wrong?

Comment: are you trying to inject stat('edit'... into a controller ?? if not what is 'edit' from a controller array injection ?

Comment: I think the problem is that I invoke controller twice - from HTML, and from state provider inside config. What the templateUrl should be, if a template is just smarty partial inside protected directory?

Comment: Your `resolve` will only work when controller is defined in state config. Should be injecting `values` not `edit` and don't use `ng-controller` in html